# GetSupportFragmentManager from non fragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The situation is this. I have a subclass of activity at the end of a long inheritance chain that I cannot change. so I cannot make my activity extend `FragmentActivity`. I wish to display dialogs without leaking them when rotations and such happen.

Google suggested mainly the (now deprecated) [dismissDialog(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dismissDialog%28int%29). The deprecation messege suggests using fragments for dialogs. which makes sense. But as I said I cannot extend `FragmentActivity` and so cannot get the fragmet manager to launch my dialog fragment. I'm also targeting min sdk 9 and would like to avoid using deprecated methods.

One solution I thought of was calling start for result on a dummy FragmentActivity to show my dialogFragment. but that seems to defeat the porpuse of dialogs entirely.

Is there any hope at all ? Can I somehow launch a dialog fragment from a non fragment activity ? Can I show and dismiss dialogs in a non deprecated way ? Any other alternative I missed ?

Comment: Why not simply manage the `Dialog` yourself across the potential screen rotation? And no you can't use the `FragmentManager` with support fragments if the Activity doesn't extend FragmentActivity.

Comment: What I am wondering about is the kind of `long inheritance chain` that would make you unable to change Activity to FragmentActivity?

Comment: @Luksprog could you expand on that ?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib well its the kind where the base activity (about 3 extends above my activity subclass, and developed by other people) overrides `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` ,which is final in `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally procedded to manually handle my dialogs. which means:

```
Dialog currentdialog; // holds the current open dialog

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        
    ...
    if(currentdialog!=null){
        currentdialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void makeDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // set some of the dialog fields
    currentdialog = alert.create();        
    currentdialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I would advice you to fix everything and extend FragmentActivity. But Anyway since can not be done without a `FragmentActivity`, here is a work-around

Create a FragmentActivity that is invisible (pretty easy with a translucent theme)

- Start this activity to handle dialogs inside it.
- Finish it when dialogs are dismissed or so.

Answer (score 0):

It  will work:

```
 CustomFieldsDialog customDialog = new    
 CustomFieldsDialog();                            
 customDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),    
 "CustomFieldsDialog");
```